# In LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4, what is the quickest way to get a Dark Wizard?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

What is the quickest way to get a Dark Wizard?

I have not completed the main quest, but would like to start going through free play to start working toward my 100%.  What is the earliest point in the story I need to be and how do I get my first Dark Wizard?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The first dark wizard I unlocked was Snape. He is in a secret area off of the potions area, taken from [this guide](http://www.xbox360achievements.org/forum/showthread.php?t=239754):

> You will unlock Profressor Snape once
>   you have access to the Secret Area in
>   the Potions room. To access this room
>   you will need a Hufflepuff character,
>   a book carrying character, and a
>   character with a key. His icon is
>   located in a chest in the Secret Area.

Comment: 1) Snape isn't a dark wizard in the game and 2) there are dark wizards who can be unlocked earlier than him.

Answer (score 3):

For what its worth, from this [tip site](http://noobgaming.com/tip/4c45e9a61cf63b5995000012), you can also get Lucius Malfoy easily:

> One of the easiest Dark Wizard to unlock is Lucius Malfoy. Play the "Follow The Spider" level in Year 2 and unlock him when you fight the giant spider (you'll need the reducto spell).

Comment: Nice - doesn't require a character with a key!  Same point in the story, though, since you can't get a character with a key earlier, afaik, than the Reducto spell.

Answer (score 1):

The earliest Dark wizard you can unlock is Barty Crouch, Jr.  He's in the first level of year 4. In freeplay you can automatically switch to Arthur Weasly ( even if you don't have him yet).  He has Reducto. At the part where you make the strength potion (towards the end of the level, after you've found everyone) use Reducto on a chest and you'll get him. He's officially the easiest and earliest dark wizard to get.

Plus, Snape isn't a dark wizard.

Answer (score 1):

Well Lucius is the earliest character you get. Do the reducto glitch and you can get dark wizards as early as year 2. What you do for the reducto glitch is you get transfiguration then go to diagon ally outside the leaky cauldren find professor quirll zap him with transfiguration and switch to the frog or rat he turns into and in around 30 seconds he'll turn back to normal you'll still be quirll so use reducto on the metal gates and go through them you'll be in knockturn ally go to the cart full of wooden boards and use the levitation spell on them there'll be a staircase go up it and you'll get Igor Karragaph buy him and he'll already have reducto now you can use him in free play an get things that require reducto like Lucius Malfoy.

Comment: .. and Griphook. This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Lucius Malfoy in the  'Follow the Spiders' level. It is in year 2, earlier than Barty Crouch Jr. You'll need to use Reducto on the chest where you fight Aragog.

Comment: But you can't get reducto until year four, (after the point where you can unlock Barty Crouch Jr).