# How to destroy granite black rock?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

My nephew and I have finished *LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4* and now we are trying to get all of the gold bricks.

We have a problem because it is not clear on how we can destroy these black granite rocks and other indestructible objects that appear in certain levels.

We understood that we need to change character using the pot potion, but we don't know which one has the power to destroy them.

Comment: Just adding a comment to link in the [following question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/in-lego-harry-potter-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-get-a-dark-wizard), since it is very relevant to someone wanting to know how to destroy the black items with red sparkles.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the rocks and objects have red sparkles around them, then they require dark magic. Dark magic can only be used by the following:

- Barty Crounch Jr.
- Deatheater
- Lord Voldemort
- Lucius Malfoy
- Peter Pettigrew
- Professer Snape
- Quirrell (Voldemort)
- Tom Riddle

[source](http://www.ps3trophies.org/forum/lego-harry-potter-years-1-4/58669-lego-harry-potter-frequently-asked-questions.html)