# How do I get Dark Characters in Lego Harry Potter?

Tags: lego-harry-potter-years-1-4

I finished the 1st year and I didn't know how to get to the dark characters and unlock them and I have only learned 2 spells. Can I go back into the 1st year and get them if so how can I do that and where do I find the dark characters?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In LEGO Harry Potter Years 1-4, what is the quickest way to get a Dark Wizard?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2628/in-lego-harry-potter-years-1-4-what-is-the-quickest-way-to-get-a-dark-wizard)

Answer (score 0):

To get Dark Characters you need to complete all of the levels in years 1-4. Then get Griphook from Gringotts. Then go to the last level of Year 2 in The Chamber of Secrets and there should be a Safe that Griphook can open which unlocks Tom Riddle who has Dark Magic

Comment: Okay. Now I have been seeing people getting like Snape and others in the first year would you happen to know how to get him/them? Thank you so much for your help by the way